# Construction of a statistical test for a test statistic that fluctuates between 0 and 1

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance

I'm working on a project where we currently take a look at some sort of efficiency measure, where we numerically integrate the area under the efficient frontier up to the current portfolios' volatility and relate that to the total area spanning the difference of the upper and lower boundary of our markowitz bullet. Here is a pic of what we are calculating at the moment:

[image]

(Sorry for the crude pic). We calculate area A and B, which also includes area A and then calculate the ratio A/B. "Aktuelle Fondsperformance" denotes the location of the current portfolio that we try to analyze. The other %-points are reference portfolios, which are not really necessary for the analysis.

At the beginning, i hoped for a more or less robust measure w.r.t. the expected mean, which turned out not to be the case as the shift of the mean of the efficient frontier and of the actual portfolio are not of the same magnitude (somewhat not surprising). Consequently, our ratio fluctuates more or less randomly between 0 and 100% with a strong tendency towards 0%:
[image]

My quesion therfore:
If i assume the mean and volatility /covariance matrix are distributed in a certain way, how can i derive some sort of test statistics for my ratio A/B, that i can use for testing and which test seems to fit best? I remember vaguely that somewhere else on stack exchange, it has been suggested to use a Chi-Square test for this, others suggested a Likelihood-Ratio test, however, I'm in doubt whether this is the test that i need as i want to test, whether my ratio indicates that area A is large (and thus my portfolio is far away from the efficient frontier) and whether the assumtions for the test statistics (i.e. the ratio A/B) are met. Which test can i use (even for a first proxy) to test whether my ratio of A/B is statistically distinct from zero?
EDIT: Here is some of my A/B ratio time-series:

| UD Measure |
| --- |
| 43.75876% |
| 40.11191% |
| 42.22972% |
| 0.00000% |
| 46.59587% |
| 39.59457% |
| 44.23689% |
| 54.71874% |
| 15.38799% |
| 21.51828% |
| 13.69063% |
| 16.15485% |
| 18.02428% |
| 15.25469% |
| 16.31505% |
| 16.50092% |
| 14.09322% |
| 15.13898% |
| 12.44043% |
| 19.45713% |
| 31.52470% |
| 28.21138% |
| 30.61654% |
| 22.29643% |
| 26.82699% |
| 26.42130% |
| 38.30203% |
| 27.88488% |
| 31.12872% |
| 27.17600% |
| 30.08507% |
| 32.23050% |
| 32.11756% |
| 35.17257% |
| 30.80349% |
| 29.30227% |
| 35.25737% |
| 34.72177% |
| 32.23960% |
| 27.68286% |
| 25.76643% |
| 27.47133% |
| 28.05801% |
| 25.21989% |
| 19.71466% |
| 15.71925% |
| 15.20805% |
| 12.07292% |
| 10.03699% |
| 12.39628% |
| 14.38509% |
| 12.24658% |
| 12.77169% |
| 12.72972% |
| 12.81976% |
| 13.45011% |
| 14.09369% |
| 15.39915% |
| 15.16695% |
| 15.14334% |
| 16.36192% |
| 12.82083% |
| 13.10037% |
| 11.85333% |
| 10.91146% |
| 10.08766% |
| 9.90633% |
| 9.48159% |
| 8.77553% |
| 8.75198% |
| 9.01672% |
| 10.97049% |
| 13.05573% |
| 10.58828% |
| 9.07151% |
| 9.34531% |
| 10.45279% |
| 9.04091% |
| 9.30546% |
| 6.24062% |
| 5.61671% |
| 7.59712% |
| 8.47359% |
| 7.88079% |
| 10.68607% |
| 10.36262% |
| 9.53478% |
| 9.05441% |
| 9.28882% |
| 9.97306% |
| 10.23855% |
| 10.13852% |
| 10.11717% |
| 9.75017% |
| 11.17651% |
| 10.63344% |
| 14.39060% |
| 14.18135% |
| 13.70984% |
| 11.85056% |
| 12.11896% |
| 12.53589% |
| 11.02927% |
| 10.61326% |
| 11.11240% |
| 11.10415% |
| 8.97054% |
| 8.86242% |
| 9.38763% |
| 10.19274% |
| 9.75143% |
| 11.51699% |
| 11.97307% |
| 13.32388% |
| 18.73914% |
| 19.58650% |
| 19.99560% |
| 18.83382% |
| 19.51774% |
| 18.25100% |
| 19.59587% |
| 16.56987% |
| 18.40695% |
| 18.96154% |
| 18.17299% |
| 17.79963% |
| 17.89769% |
| 20.88173% |
| 21.01258% |
| 19.12773% |
| 19.11817% |
| 16.88853% |
| 18.97545% |
| 19.10814% |
| 19.47740% |
| 20.32827% |
| 19.01270% |
| 17.33200% |
| 17.90234% |
| 17.93781% |
| 19.29544% |
| 18.67243% |
| 18.44626% |
| 18.91128% |
| 19.15763% |
| 19.92883% |
| 17.75099% |
| 17.35439% |
| 17.12208% |
| 17.76890% |
| 17.65641% |
| 18.43705% |
| 21.56876% |
| 22.00833% |
| 18.34353% |
| 19.26247% |

I appreciate any hint
Thanks a lot
Thomas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146219/discussion-between-t123-and-ute).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146222/discussion-on-question-by-t123-construction-of-a-statistical-test-for-a-test-sta); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.